# Create function to update two tables in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, stored-functions

I have two table, with different columns, and I have to create a function to update the second table with the information from the first when the columns year match with the given year and group all in gender groups.

Here I put my code but I don't know if it is okay because the pgAdmin4 returns me an error because of the $$ symbols, although I am trying to solve it.

```
BEGIN WORK;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_report(p_year INTEGER) 
RETURNS SETOF report1 AS $$
DECLARE report report1;
BEGIN
UPDATE report1 SET m.num=t_num, m.na=t_na, m.nd=t_nd, m.birth=t_birth
FROM report2 m
    FULL JOIN report1
    ON p_year= m.year
GROUP BY m.gender);

   --In case there are any film in the specified year
IF NOT FOUND THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION  ‘’%: No film exists in this year’’, -746;
END IF;
RETURN report;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

COMMIT WORK;
```

Can someone just tell if it is okay? Thanks

Comment: the `group by` without any aggregates is most definitely wrong. And you have a stray `)` after it. that's the obvious syntax errors I can see

Comment: Creates a cross join because I previously declare report1?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what "group by gender" is supposed to mean, but I think you are looking for a simple UPDATE.

Note that you should **not** repeat the target table in the FROM clause of an UPDATE statement.

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html)

> Note that the target table must not appear in the from_list, unless you intend a self-join

You didn't show us any sample data and expected results or the structure of the tables, so I can only guess, what exactly you want, but something like this maybe:

```
UPDATE report1 r1
   SET num = r2.t_num, 
       na = r2.t_na, 
       nd = r2.t_nd
       birth = r.t_birth
FROM report2 r2
WHERE r1.year = r2.year
  AND r1.gender = r2.gender
  AND r1.year = p_year= m.year;
```

If you want to return all rows that have been changed, then you can use the `RETURNING` clause. You don't need a `declare` for that. Using `language sql` instead of PL/pgSQL makes this even simpler:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_report(p_year INTEGER) 
   RETURNS SETOF report1 
AS $$
  UPDATE report1 r1
     SET num = r2.t_num, 
         na = r2.t_na, 
         nd = r2.t_nd
         birth = r.t_birth
  FROM report2 r2
  WHERE r1.year = r2.year
    AND r1.gender = r2.gender
    AND r1.year = p_year= m.year
  RETURNING r1.*; --<< return all modified rows
$$ 
LANGUAGE sql;
```